# Strange error on building app

Tags: c#

When I tried to build my source I saw that strange error :

> Error 1   Unexpected error creating debug information file
>   'C:\Users\Pluse Konto\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\xxx\xxx\obj\x86\Debug\xxx.PDB' -- 'Indefinited error.
>   ' xxx

I removed file `xxx.PDB`, but it has been not again created. I don't know what is the reason of that. Except that, I don't see any other syntax or compiler error.

**@EDIT**

I built my app as relase and now every thing works ok . Do you know what is the reason of my issue ?

Comment: Have you cleaned, rebuild your solution?, Have you deleted bin,obj folders and tried again? have you restarted VS?

Comment: Try all I said and let me know

Comment: Now every thing works ok ! Do you think I should reinstall my enviroment ?

Comment: Can't get you does that helps or you're kidding?

Comment: I've written : That was helpful for me and solved my problem. But my VS10 Express often has strange errors like "Debugger has been disconected from clients", etc. So I ask : Should I reinstall VS10 ?

Comment: Oh I see, If you try migrating to Vs2012 which looks promising never crashed with me but Vs2010 crashed often.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you write that as answer ? I will accept it.

Comment: I don't know about a solution for this, but one thing that has caused this error for me (and continues to) is when you have project resources in dropbox (or similar). Like this, when you build it again, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't fit to be an answer though, I write this on request.

Anybody facing problems like this or any kind of build error saying `Cannot access the file...` Try the following. Most of the time this should solve your problem.

1. Try cleaning the solution and rebuild your solution.
2. Deleted `bin` and `obj` folders manually and try again.
3. Worst case you may have to restart VS.

Problem should go off.

Additionally you could migrate to VS2012 which I feel promising(with less issues) when compared to earlier releases. It atmost crashed twice but previous versions do often.